# Search in Laravel with the value of Array

Tags: laravel, search, laravel-5.6

I am building a search with multi filter app in laravel. It works fine until i have many checkbox for certain request, Like age. If i just check for a single value, search function works fine. But if i check for 2 or more values it won't search. Can anyone help me with this.

Here is my Controller

```
if ($request->has('age')) {
    $age = $request->input('age');
    $ageString = implode(" , ", $age);
    $nursery->where('acceptingAge',  'LIKE', '%' . $ageString . '%');
}
```

Here is my form

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="1year" name="age[]" value="5 years old">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="1year" name="age[]" value="4 years old">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your acceptingAge data was like "5 years old,3 years old,1 years old"

How about

```
$nursery= new Nursery;
if($request->has('age')){
    foreach($request->input('age') as $age){
        $nursery= $nursery->where('acceptingAge',  'LIKE', '%' . $age . '%');
    }
}
$nursery->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i tried it but and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$nersery->whereIn('acceptingAge', $age);
```

for more info about whereIn:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses

**Update**

Try this

```
$nersery->where(function($query) use ($age) {

    foreach ($age as $key => $a) {

        if ($key === 0) {

            $query = $query->where('acceptingAge', $a);

            continue;

        }

        $query = $query->orWhere('acceptingAge', $a);

    }

});
```

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work. No search results with matching value too

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the data from your DB that you are trying to compare against?

Comment: $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
      
            $table->text('acceptingAge');
            $table->string('fees');
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: Can you please give me an example of an age in the acceptingAge column?

Comment: acceptingAge
4 years old, 5 years old, 6 years old, 5 years old